# Nifi ExecuteStreamCommand returns UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, apache-nifi, unicode-normalization

I am executing a python script within Nifi via ExecuteStreamCommand. When I run the file within the command line, I do not get any errors, and the output is correct. When I run the same file within Nifi- I recieve a unicode error. Is there a workaround for this?

**error log:**

```
'unicodeencodeerror python 'charmap' codec can't encode charecter '\u221'
```

I am saving a pandas df that consists of multiple data types. The code that is envoking the error:

```
wo_new.to_csv(sys.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
```

**Within Nifi ExecuteStreamCommand Properties:**

command path: Python

command arguments: references location of .py file

**Things I have already tried:**

- forcing  utf-8 encoding
- forcing windows encoding cp1252 (the type that the error log says anaconda is referencing)
- enabling unicode via these two techniques https://vladikk.com/2017/03/30/nifi-unicode/
- normalizing the df to ascii via unicodedata (this application didn't work- .str errors for aplying at a column level as well as to single string)

Answer (score 0):

Forcing utf-8 encoding on each column with text seemed to do the trick. I don't know why applying the encoding when saving the output didn't do the trick. I used the following code:

```
x.str.encode('utf-8')
```